# $SU(n)=O(2n)\cap SL(n,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: group-theory

From the two-out-of-three property, $$U(n)=O(2n)\cap GL(n,\mathbb{C})\label{1}$$ where it is understood that $\mathit{GL}(n,\Bbb C) \hookrightarrow\mathit{GL}(2n,\Bbb R)$. My question is, is the following true? $$SU(n)=O(2n)\cap SL(n,\mathbb{C})\tag{1}$$
Intituitively I would say yes -- if in $A=B\cap C$ I impose that elements of $C$ have unit determinant, then so should elements of $A$. What bothers me is the embedding of $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ in $GL(2n,\Bbb R)$. We embed a matrix $$A=(a+ib)\in GL(1,\Bbb C)$$
with determinant $det A=a+ib$ as $$\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2,\Bbb R),$$
which has determinant $|detA|^2$. This leads me to think that imposing unitarity of the determinant on $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ is not the same as imposing it on $GL(2n,\Bbb R)$ and therefore that (1) may be untrue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the inclusion
$$i:GL_n(\mathbb{C})\to GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R}).$$
As you've noticed, this has the property that $\det(i(A))=|\det(A)|^2$. It is easy to see this from your comment by diagonalization. Thus, for example, we get that $$SU(N)\neq SO(2N)\cap \text{GL}(\mathbb{C},N),$$
as the determinant used in $SO(2N)$ is for $i(A)$ not $A$.

On the other hand, you are are asking about restriction to $SL(\mathbb{C},N)$, which uses the determinant for $A$. So indeed we do have that
$$SU(N)=O(2N)\cap SL(\mathbb{C},N).$$

Comment: Thanks! In fact I was also interested in the case with $O(2n)$ replaced by $SO(2n)$, so you answered my second question before I even got to ask it. Is $SO(2n)\cap GL(\Bbb C,n)$ any named group?

Comment: @user56517852 Its still just $U(N)$.  Any element in $U(N)$ already has that $|\det(A)|^2=1$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!